# Picasso Image Loader in ListView

Tags: android, listview, picasso

i am facins strange problem nowadays. I use picasso library to download and shows images in listview.

I use target for changing imageview size in runtime. And there is

```
private List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>();
```

list top of the class.

Here is complete getView method ;

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {


    final CategoryMoneyViewHolder categoryMoneyViewHolder;


    if (getItem(position) instanceof MoneyItem) {


        final MoneyItem moneyItem = (MoneyItem) getItem(position);

        if (row == null) {


            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_category_money, parent, false);


            categoryMoneyViewHolder = new CategoryMoneyViewHolder();


            categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyNameTextView = (RDATextView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_money_textview_money_name);
            categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyThumbImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_money_imageview_money_thumb);
            categoryMoneyViewHolder.detailTextView = (RDATextView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_money_textview_details);


            row.setTag(categoryMoneyViewHolder);


        } else {


            categoryMoneyViewHolder = (CategoryMoneyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyNameTextView.setText(moneyItem.getName());


        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new MoneyDetailFragment().open(activity, PassingDataKeyConstants.MONEY, moneyItem);


            }
        });





        final String URLString = BaseService.MONEY_PICTURE + moneyItem.getFront_thumb();


        Target target = new Target() {


            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {


                if (SettingsForEnablesConstants.ENABLE_PICASSO_LOG) {


                    RDALogger.debug("onBitmapLoaded by : " + position + " " + URLString);
                }


                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyThumbImageView.getLayoutParams();

                double screenWidth = RDADeviceHelpers.getScreenWidth(activity) - RDAResourcesHelpers.getDimen(activity, R.dimen._20dp) * 2;

                double ratioFloat = screenWidth / bitmap.getWidth();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (ratioFloat * bitmap.getHeight());

                layoutParams.width = (int) screenWidth;

                categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyThumbImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                //---------gelen resme gore para gorseli boyutlandirilmasi


                categoryMoneyViewHolder.moneyThumbImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }


            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {


                if (SettingsForEnablesConstants.ENABLE_PICASSO_LOG) {


                    RDALogger.error("onBitmapFailed by :" + URLString);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {


                if (SettingsForEnablesConstants.ENABLE_PICASSO_LOG) {


                    RDALogger.debug("onPrepareLoad by :" + URLString);
                }
            }
        };


        targets.add(target);


        Picasso.with(activity).load(URLString).into(target);


    } else {


    }


    return row;
}
```

For now everything perfect. But my server has sequrity headers to load images. So i need to use downloader with picasso. Here is code ;

```
final Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(activity);


        builder.downloader(new UrlConnectionDownloader(activity) {


            @Override
            protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {


                HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);

                for (Map.Entry entry : RequestHelpers.getRequestHeadersMap().entrySet()) {


                    connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                }


                return connection;
            }
        });


        Picasso picasso = builder.build();

        picasso.setLoggingEnabled(SettingsForEnablesConstants.ENABLE_PICASSO_LOG);


        picasso.load(URLString).into(target);
```

When i put this downloader code into adapter. Every images loads over and over while scrolling. And stucks in scrolling. I dont understand why and where is wrong?

Any opinion?

Thanks from now.

Comment: Shouldn't `final Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(activity);` be a member of Adapter and `builder.downloader(..)` be initialized at Adapter constructor?

Comment: @Serg you are my best friend. Images load once but listview scroll still stucks